# ggplot boxplot y axis not displaying correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, yaxis

This seems like it should be an easy fix but my googling has lead me to no answers.  I guess I'm just not quite sure what is happening or how to describe it in my searches.  I'm working with a big data set containing many variables related to the development rates of the Coffee Berry Borer at different study sites.  I'm trying to produce boxplots of berry moisture samples by collection date, for each site individually.  The code I'm using is as follows:

```
ggplot(subset(AllData, Site %in% c("Kona High"))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Collection.Date, y=X..Moisture, group=Collection.Date))
```

This is what I'm getting.

[image]

Does anyone know what is up with the y axis?  Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: `X..Moisture` is a factor. Needs to be continuous. Probably a problem with your data import step.

Comment: Can you please provide a subset of your data?

Comment: Thank you Richard Telford!  I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking.  Should have known to check that!